# Can ElasticSearch Cluster have nodes with different memory size and different number of CPU core?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am using ElasticSearch6.2.1, going to move to multi-node cluster. My current node has 32GB memory and 4 CPU core (3.6 Gz). ES heap size is 8GB. My new node has 16GB Memory and same similar CPU. Can I create my ES cluster using these two nodes?

Comment: Yes .. you are free to use any combination of hardware. But having same configuration nodes will help distribute load properly

Comment: Is there any impact on performance if there is heterogeneous nodes?

Comment: the only thing is you won't be able to size your cluster predict scaling